ReadProcessMemory: Why can I not see the contents of notepad.exe?
I've written the following code to try to read from notepad.exe. I succeed in reading everything from memory, but I cannot find the text I've typed into notepad.exe. Where did I go wrong?
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace MemoryAcessor;

public partial class MemoryRead
{
    const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;

    [LibraryImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static partial IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

    [LibraryImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static partial bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, Int64 lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);  

    public static void Main()
    {
        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad")[0];
        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, (uint)process.Id);       
        
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1<<25];
        var result = ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, process.MainModule!.BaseAddress, buffer, buffer.Length, out var bytesRead);

        Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result} ({bytesRead} bytes)");
        Console.WriteLine("=======================");
        Console.WriteLine(buffer[0..(int)bytesRead]);
        Console.WriteLine("=======================");
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer[0..(int)bytesRead]));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

In openend notepad.exe (Win11Pro), typed "Hello World!", then ran the above code.
I can't figure out, is this because my conversion is wrong (UTF8) or because am I reading from the wrong module?

You are trying to read unsaved text in a Notepad.exe session? This is extremely hacky. You would need to identify how Notepad works internally, where the temporary data is stored (possibly on the stack or in cache) and read from there. You're better off saving the text as a file and simply reading the file. What makes you think your code should work as-is? You are reading the actual binary for the Notepad executable. process.MainModule!.BaseAddress is going to be a PE header for the file, not the volatile data in a Notepad session.

To get the current text of the Notepad window, you'll have better luck navigating the window hierarchy to the Edit control within in and then calling GetWindowText() on that.

@h0r53 this is just meant as a toy example to access another process' memory. What makes me think the code should work as is? Well, I'd assume that typing into notepad.exe causes it to save it somewhere in its memory and since I'm reading everything I'd expect to find it there.

You can read the memory of a process, but you can't simply start at the base address of the module and expect to get volatile runtime data. The base address is quite literally the start of the binary data for the file, which in this case will be a PE header. You'll need to reverse engineer the binary to identify where the data may actually be. Most likely, it's stored somewhere on the Stack or the Heap, which will be very far away from the module base address.

@h0r53 I'm not yet conviced I totally understand. I get that I won't find the data at the stat of base_address but I'm reading around 2MB of data (=everything) from that address and I can't find it anywhere in there. Is the stack/heap not located in there? Also see my last question, does that mean I have to read from another module (afterall there are 100+ modules in notepad.exe). Or would I need to find a memory adress in that memory, that points to a location on the heap and resolve that address? I guess that becomes a futile exercise, but at least in theory...

The stack/heap is certainly not located in the same segment as the module's base address. It likely isn't even close. The module's base address is typically going to include the .text segment, .rodata and other static content. The Windows API VirtualQueryEx should be able to identify the stack and heap addresses of a process though. Also, if you have any experience with reverse engineering then you can identify precisely where text buffers are stored by Notepad. You may find it useful to try the program "Cheat Engine" for monitoring a Windows program and scanning memory.

The text in a Notepad window is going to be buried in a window managed by user32.dll. You might consider creating a dead simple WinForms app with a multiline text box, running it, and then spelunking around your app with the debugger (Notepad is basically a window, a textbox and a bit of code to add the menu functionality).

@Flydog57 thanks for the tip! Yeah that was plan B.

This should get you a step closer to what you are trying to achieve. As mentioned in comments, the text buffers used by Nodepad.exe are not going to be at the module's base load address. Instead, it is very likely that those buffers are located either on the stack or the heap of the process. Here is a modified version of your code that attempts to identify the location of the stack and heap through using the Windows API VirtualQueryEx.
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace MemoryAccessor
{
    public partial class MemoryRead
    {
        const int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;
        const int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool VirtualQueryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, out MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer, uint dwLength);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr BaseAddress;
            public IntPtr AllocationBase;
            public uint AllocationProtect;
            public IntPtr RegionSize;
            public uint State;
            public uint Protect;
            public uint Type;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
            if (processes.Length > 0)
            {
                Process process = processes[0];
                IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, process.Id);

                if (processHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    IntPtr lpAddress = IntPtr.Zero;
                    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

                    while (VirtualQueryEx(processHandle, lpAddress, out mbi, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION))) != false)
                    {
                        // Check if the region is part of the stack or heap
                        if (mbi.Protect == 0x04 && mbi.Type == 0x10000) // PAGE_READWRITE and MEM_COMMIT
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Base Address: {mbi.BaseAddress}, Region Size: {mbi.RegionSize}");
                            Console.WriteLine("Placeholder: Read from stack here");

                            // Here you can read from the stack by using ReadProcessMemory
                            // For example:
                            // byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            // IntPtr bytesRead;
                            // ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, mbi.BaseAddress, buffer, buffer.Length, out bytesRead);
                        }
                        else if (mbi.Protect == 0x04 && mbi.Type == 0x20000) // PAGE_READWRITE and MEM_PRIVATE
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Base Address: {mbi.BaseAddress}, Region Size: {mbi.RegionSize}");
                            Console.WriteLine("Placeholder: Read from heap here");

                            // Here you can read from the heap by using ReadProcessMemory
                            // For example:
                            // byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            // IntPtr bytesRead;
                            // ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, mbi.BaseAddress, buffer, buffer.Length, out bytesRead);
                        }

                        lpAddress = IntPtr.Add(mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize.ToInt32());
                    }

                    CloseHandle(processHandle);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to open process.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Process not found.");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

I left placeholder code for where you'd want to try reading from the stack and heap.
Alternatively, you could try a program such as "Cheat Engine" which monitors the address space of a program. That would help you quickly search for the text entered into Notepad and identify where in memory that data is. You'd still need to do some calculations to determine how you can reliably do the same programmatically.

Thanks for the code, that hints to some nice material I have to read. I had to change the pointer advancement to lpAddress = mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize;, otherwise it would overflow on 64bit.  However, I still can't find "Hello" in any of that (I printed the bytes to a file and ran dngrep on it). Is there something else that could be going on, or is this now the point, where I would have to figure out what the hell notepad.exe is doing internally? Like perhaps it's not storing it as a contingenous array in memory, thus I can't CTRL+f for it?

@infinitezero try using Cheat Engine to search the address space of the program for the text in Notepad. If it can find it, it will show you where in memory the text buffers are. If you still don't find the text, it's possible that Notepad is storing that data in a temporary file. Maybe check AppData on Windows for any Notepad process files.

Note: I know you said you are doing this on Windows 11, and I did this on Windows 10, but you should be able to follow the steps to get it working on Windows 11, it just may be a bit more complex since notepad can have multiple tabs on Windows 11
You can read the text in notepad by finding the memory offset of where notepad stores the text (will still work after restarting the app). I did this using Cheat Engine, here are my steps:

Start by searching for the string value type and the value that you put in notepad using Cheat Engine. Here you can see I got one result that shows the address of where the text is currently stored. Double click on that result to add it to the list at the bottom of cheat engine.




Double click on the address and then copy it.




Change the value type to 8 Bytes (for x64 processes), check the Hex checkbox, and paste the address you copied into the address field, then scan and add the result to the list at the bottom by double clicking it.




Repeat steps 2 and 3 until one of the the addresses in the results is green, which means you found the offset pointing to the text. You can then use this offset to read the text from memory, even after the program restarts.


As shown in the screenshot, the address where the pointer is that notepad uses in windows 10 is notepad.exe+31680, which can be represented in C# like this:
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
IntPtr.Add(process.MainModule!.BaseAddress, 0x31680); // notepad.exe+31680

Sometimes you might need to use the code below instead if the offset isn't from the main module:
static IntPtr GetModuleBaseAddress(Process process, string moduleName)
{
    ProcessModuleCollection modules = process.Modules;
    foreach (ProcessModule module in modules)
    {
        if (module.ModuleName == moduleName)
        {
            return module.BaseAddress;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception($"Module {moduleName} not found in process {process.ProcessName}");
}

Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
// You can see all modules by looping through `process.Modules`
// Replace notepad.exe with the name of the module. Might be called something like `textinputframework.dll`
IntPtr addressOfTextPointer1 = IntPtr.Add(GetModuleBaseAddress(process, "notepad.exe"), 0x31680);

The problem with this is that if you read whats at the address, you will get a pointer to another address instead of the text, so you need to read the pointer and then the pointer from that pointer etc. until you get the text.

You can see that notepad.exe+31680 (7FF78F051680) points to 1E5CC990008 which points to 1E5C79E6880 which points to the UTF-16 Unicode string hello world.
Here is my full code that I used to follow the pointers and get the text, which will still work after you restart the program because the original pointer will always be the same offset from the module/process base address:
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public partial class Program
{
    // Number of characters to read from the target process
    static int charactersToRead = 11;

    [LibraryImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static partial IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

    [LibraryImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static partial bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, long lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
            IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(0x0010, false, (uint)process.Id);
            IntPtr addressOfTextPointer1 = IntPtr.Add(process.MainModule!.BaseAddress, 0x31680);
            //IntPtr addressOfTextPointer1 = IntPtr.Add(GetModuleBaseAddress(process, "notepad.exe"), 0x31680);
            Console.WriteLine("Pointer 1: " + addressOfTextPointer1.ToString("X"));
            long addressOfTextPointer2 = BitConverter.ToInt64(ReadMem(processHandle, addressOfTextPointer1, 8));
            Console.WriteLine("Pointer 2: " + addressOfTextPointer2.ToString("X"));
            long addressOfText = BitConverter.ToInt64(ReadMem(processHandle, addressOfTextPointer2, 8));
            Console.WriteLine("Address of string: " + addressOfText.ToString("X"));
            Console.WriteLine("String: " + Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ReadMem(processHandle, addressOfText, charactersToRead * 2)));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static byte[] ReadMem(nint processHandle, long address, int bufferLength)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
        ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, buffer.Length, out var bytesRead);
        return buffer;
    }

    // Helper function to get the base address of a module in the target process
    static IntPtr GetModuleBaseAddress(Process process, string moduleName)
    {
        ProcessModuleCollection modules = process.Modules;
        foreach (ProcessModule module in modules)
        {
            if (module.ModuleName == moduleName)
            {
                return module.BaseAddress;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception($"Module {moduleName} not found in process {process.ProcessName}");
    }
}

Output:
Pointer 1: 7FF78F051680
Pointer 2: 1E5CC990008
Address of string: 1E5C79E6880
String: hello world

Useful research/sources/tools that I used to figure this all out. This might help if the above steps don't work for some reason:

Cheat Engine Website
Cheat Engine Tutorial: Multilevel Pointers
Function for reading a string from memory (GitHub)
How To Find Offsets, Entity Addresses & Pointers
Using Base Pointers with Offset to Read Process Memory

